# Solutions to allow non-developer to define a Workflow Foundation 4 processes

Tags: .net, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, designer

We are to deliver a SenseNet ECM based custom solution to our client. Solution includes a flexible business process declaration capability. SenseNet fits us in many ways, except all the demos we've evaluated today show one big disadvantage - `XAML` Workflow Foundation files are used to create a logical workflow implementations (sorry for the terminology mess). In Visual Studio. We can't ship something that requires VS to fully function to our clients, nor we can say "hey, we'll just do it for you every time you need it".

Is there an ready-to-use solutions that allows defining .Net 4 WF `xaml`s in a more user-frienldy environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rehost the workflow designer, used by Visual Studio, on your own WPF application:

**[Rehosting the Workflow Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489451.aspx)**:

- [Task 1: To create the WPF Application project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489414.aspx)
- [Task 2: Host the Workflow Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489407.aspx)
- [Task 3: Create the Toolbox and PropertyGrid Panes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489433.aspx)

(also check [this blog post](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx?ocid=aff-n-we-loc--DEV40909&WT.mc_id=aff-n-we-loc--DEV40909), for a quicker introduction, including a sample solution)